# I use at-command for get Caller ID but just write ok ring

Tags: c#, at-command

I am using the following method to detect the `CallerID` when someone calls.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
    serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
    serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
    serialPort1.Open();
    serialPort1.WriteLine("AT+VCID=1" + System.Environment.NewLine);
}

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text += serialPort1.ReadLine();
}
```

I excepted something like this :

```
RING               //On 1st Ring
DATE = xxxxx       //On 2nd Ring
TIME = xxxx
NMBR = xxxxxxxxx

RING               //On 3rd Ring    
RING               //On 4th Ring
```

But I have just :

```
OK
RING
RING
RING
```

NOTE:

line support `CallerID`

I guess modem support `CallerID` too because I see the word RING for each incoming ring

**Confirmed:** I have caller id device and I checked it; I'm sure that I have caller id service.

Comment: I believe *`"AT+VCID=1" + System.Environment.NewLine`* is the problem. You need a `\r`, not a `\n`. So try with `"AT+VCID=1" + Chr(13)`. You may want to try with a `ATZ + Chr(13)` as a base case. You should get `OK` as a response. Also, you can query the modem for Caller Id commands with `AT+VCID=?`. You should get back something like `(0-2)` and then `OK`. Also see [Unexpected response to ATZ when attempting to configure USB modem?](https://superuser.com/q/1405831/173513) on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 6):

You need to setup calling line presentation on your device I believe. Just send the command:

```
AT+CLIP=1
```

You should then see that when the number is called the following will be displayed:

```
+CLIP 1234567890
```

Comment: `AT+CLIP` is cellular. It is probably not available in a V.92 modem.

Answer (score 1):

most common CALLER ID command is "AT#CID=1"

Answer (score 0):

Found that commands

```
AT#CID=1
AT#CC1
AT+VCID=1
AT%CCID=1
AT*ID1
```

No one worked because of... linefeed (facepalm). So try them with \r\n or \n

Answer (score -1):

i had a similar issue .  i changed to different usb modem. it worked fine.